# Is it possible to mock the result of a function triggered by a button click with testcafe/node?

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is it possible to mock the result of a function triggered by a button click with testcafe/node for UI testing? Selenium/capybara has the 'allow_any_instance_of(...).to receive(..) syntax.

So the router receives "choice" from the body and instantiates a new Game - I want to mock the random argument function given to the Game. I have already mocked random when testing the Game model but want to also mock the result on the user interface using Testcafe.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let choice = req.body.choice,
  game = new Game( choice, random ),
  houseChoice = '',
  result = game.calcWinner( random );
  houseChoice = game.houseChoice;
  res.render('rps', { choice: choice,
                      first_name: first_name,
                      last_name: last_name,
                      random: houseChoice,
                      result: result });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

TestСafe operates with the same concepts as a web page: HTML element, url, HTTP request.
It means you can mock an http request, override any Javascript code on a tested page.

If you need to mock the HTTP request, take a look at the step-by-step instruction here - https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/mocking-http-requests.html.

Comment: Yes i read the docs but that only works for http requests, couldn't get it to work for mocking a function

Comment: A function result can be different: sending an http request, showing a modal popup, setting a cookie value.
Would you please clarify what result you want to mock?

Comment: I see your posted the code of the function. Please also provide more information about the function result: the content type (e.g. json, text/html) and the response text.

Comment: the  function just returns a string - so I want to create a mock function that returns a string - the response text is also a string

Answer (score 1):

If your router code is executed on the server, you can use [RequestMock](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/mocking-http-requests.html) to respond with a pre-rendered content. Otherwise, you can implement [Dependency Injection](https://medium.com/sharenowtech/dependency-injection-in-a-javascript-planet-1093b4c0af4a) to mock the `random` function.